# Mindfulness With Breathing & Ear Pain

Tags: meditation

Whenever I do mindfulness with breathing I get ear pains whenever I do longer breaths. The breath is also hearable.

Wherein lies the problem?

Comment: Physical pain and itching is normal time to time but in your case the cause can be something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I figured it out by myself how to solve the pain. It was due to me breathing in a quite 'rough' manner, namely, breathing through the nose so that the sound is audible.

Consequently, changing the breath so that it's hardly audible diminished the ear & head pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are performing forced breaths.

Otherwise, there could possibly be some type of physical problem or blockage, such as [this](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/chronic-sinusitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20351661) I found on the internet.

If the later, I would research the internet, ask a doctor or ask a highly skilled acupuncturist.

Comment: Before proceeding with the latter, lets assume that it's the former reason. What'd you suggest?

Comment: Anapanasati long breathing is not forced or controlled breathing. It is long breathing that naturally occurs when the mind is calm.

Comment: Why then does everyone (Ajahn Chah, Buddhadasa, Jayasaro etc.) say to tranquilize the breath and observe it?

Comment: Tranquilize does not mean directly manipulating it. You can keep following their instructions and see what results they bring.